# Stiff ODE solver in the web browser

Tags: ode, implicit-methods, java

I'd like to make a web application that lets people play with solving ODE systems, changing parameters with sliders etc. but instead of doing the computations on the server side, solving the equations on their own computer via the web-browser.

There's some really nice examples here: http://blog.littleredcomputer.net/jekyll/update/2016/04/03/diffeq-javascript.html using this javascript library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/odex

But the ODE system I want to play with is pretty stiff, so would almost certainly need an implicit, and probably adaptive timestep, solver like CVODE. Does anyone know whether any libraries exist for that?

Comment: The easiest way to get some of this using any solver, RK4 for instance, is to scale the vector field to be bounded or sub-linear. That is, if the original vector field is $(u(x,y),v(x,y))$, then scale $(t'(s),x'(s),y'(s))=(1,u,v)/\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}$. Or if $u=xa+yb$, $v=xc+yd$ in some natural way, then divide by $\sqrt{1+a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}$. This does not address stability around asymptotes, but normalizes sharp turns and divergences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am the author of `diffeq-js` (https://github.com/martinjrobins/diffeq-js), which is a javascript library for solving DAE (and ODE) models in the browser using WebAssembly.

Compilation of the DAE/ODE model to WebAssembly is done on a backend server and the resultant WASM module is sent to the client. The actual solving of the model is done in the browser using the Sundials IDAS solver, which satisfies the requirement of dealing with a stiff system (Like CVODE, the IDAS solver is part of the Sundials solver suite https://github.com/LLNL/sundials)

You can see an interactive demo of diffeq-js here: https://martinjrobins.github.io/diffeq-web/

Note that most of the Sundials suite of software is written in C, and I have found that the following components can be compiled to WASM with no changes using the Emscripten SDK (https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk):

- Serial N_Vector (`nvector/nvector_serial.h`)
- Dense SUNMatrix (`sunmatrix/sunmatrix_dense.h`)
- Dense SUNLinearSolver solver (`sunlinsol/sunlinsol_dense.h`)
- IDAS (`idas/idas.h`)

So another option would be to write your model as a C project using Sundials and CVODE (I have not tried to compile CVODE, but assume it would be straightforward), compile this to WASM and then use this in some javascript on your webpage (note `diffeq-js` uses the WASI browser shim for the WASM runtime environment - https://github.com/bjorn3/browser_wasi_shim)